# Assign specific roles from where the user clicks

Tags: laravel

I would like to assign roles depending on which button the user clicks:

[image: botones para redirigir]

For example:
- If you click on I want to be an Advisor, redirect to the Laravel registration form and assign the role of advisor.
- If the user clicks on I want to be a Buyer, they redirect to the Laravel registration form and assign the buyer role.

But I do not know how to do it.
I have this code in my 'RegisterController':

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
       //'password' => Hash::make($data['password']), //mutador en User model
        'password' => $data['password'],
        'surname1' => $data['surname1'],
        'surname2' => $data['surname2'],
        'comunidad_id' => $data['cbx_comunidad'],
        'provincia_id' => $data['cbx_provincia'],  
        'municipio_id' => $data['cbx_municipio'],
    ]);

    //dd(Request::url());
    // $user->assignRole('Asesor');
    //quiero asignar varios roles depende de el botón que clicken

    return $user;

}
```

For now, what I have done is to add such a parameter, in the view that calls the view 'register':

```
href="{{ route('register','Asesor') }}"
```

and in the view 'register' send it by post in a hidden:

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php
  $pos = strpos(Request::fullUrl(), '?');                       
  $cadena = substr (Request::fullUrl() , $pos+1, strlen(Request::fullUrl()) );                                                
?>
  <input type="hidden" name="role" id="role" value="{{ $cadena }}">
</div>
```

Then in the controller I do this:

```
if ($data['role'] == 'Asesor=')
{
   $user->assignRole('Asesor');
}
return $user;
```

But I don't know if it's the right way to act.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you could work with events like this:
In your EventServiceProvider class, create an item inside your property $listen:

```
'App\Events\User\Created' => ['App\Listeners\User\AssignRoles'],
```

After that, you going to run the command:

```
php artisan event:generate
```

Now, you need to turn on this event in your User class declaring protected property $dispatchesEvents, like this:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = ['created' => 'App\Events\User\Created'];
```

After all call create method in your User class, the created event is going to be called and run AssignRoles logic.

In your App\Events\User\Created class you need to inject User into __construct method, like this:

```
public $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

Remember to put the complete path of User class!

This is the object that is going to be filled with data coming from User::create method.

Inside your Listener AssignRoles you have the event linked with the user filled and you can get it this way:

```
public function handle(Created $event)
{
    $event->user;
    // ...
}
```

Inside your Listener AssignRoles you can get all Requested params in your __construct method:

```
private $request;
public function __construct(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $this->request      = $request;
}
```

With requested params in your hand you can apply the logic depending on the clicked button inside handle method:

```
public function handle(Created $event)
{
    $event->user;
    // here is the best place to do all the logic about roles that is going to be attached in this user. E.g:
    switch($role = $this->request->role) {
        case $role == 'Asesor':
            $event->user->roles()->assignRole('Asesor');
        break;
        case $role == 'Buyer':
            $event->user->roles()->assignRole('Buyer');
        break;
    }
}
```

To send role param into Request you need to create a form with hidden element,

```
<input type='hidden' name='role' />
```

create more than one submit button to fill role hidden element

```
<input type='submit' value='I want to be an Advisor' onClick='setRole("Advisor")' />

<input type='submit' value='I want to be a Buyer' onClick='setRole("Buyer")' />
```

And, finally you need a logic to setRole js method. Good Look. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For assign Role to user.

> Controller function will be like.

```
 /* assign role */

        if(is_array($request['role']))
        {
            foreach($request['role'] as $d)
            {
                $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('id',$d)->first());
            }

        }

       return redirect()->route();
```